# azure app service basic api security

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have running the basic todoitem app service running on azure. Calling the below url will display the content in the todoitem table. How can I add basic security to prevent this data from being accessed by anyone, like a basic parameter, ToDoItem?MyToken=12345.

https://MyappService.azurewebsites.net/tables/ToDoItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I add basic security to prevent this data from being accessed by anyone, like a basic parameter, ToDoItem?MyToken=12345.

I would recommend you using the build-in [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview).

> App Service supports five identity providers out of the box: Azure Active Directory, Facebook, Google, Microsoft Account, and Twitter. To expand the built-in support, you can integrate another identity provider or [your own custom identity solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth).

Here are some great tutorials, you could refer to them:

For Node.js backend, you could follow [30 DAYS OF AZURE MOBILE APPS](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/).

For developing azure mobile apps with C#, you could follow [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/).